# Pay for labor on manufacturer replacement of engine?

Tags: engine, service, recall

We have a 2012 Kia Soul that is part of the recent recall for engine gas temperature possibly causing damage to the catalytic converter and engine. I have been fighting with the dealership and Kia to replace the engine and catalytic converter because there is evidence that they were damaged. The dealership is saying Kia is offering to provide for replacement of the engine ($7200) but are asking us to pay for the labor (approximately $1500). Is there any legitimate reason we should have to pay for the labor or is the dealership or Kia just trying not to take as big of a hit on this?

Comment: What do you mean by "recall?" In the US, for example, a government-mandated recall is wholly paid for by the manufacturer, at no charge to the owner. A "service action," OTOH (may be known by other names), is initiated by the manufacturer, and may or or may not cover all the costs.

Comment: If they are offering to stump up for the engine and, as part of that agreement or arrangement, you have to pay a contribution then you may be getting a reasonable deal. Otherwise, they may say that there is not sufficient damage to warrant replacement and just offer an extension to the warranty period. So, take care how you play the game...

Comment: @David The recall is only officially for the software that controls the catalytic converter overheating. Kia is resisting issuing a full recall on the engines and catalytic converters.

Comment: I agree with Solar Mike. They will undoubtedly say that. In this grey area (your expert says damage was caused by the faulty EGT software; they say it's out of warranty, either there's no damage, or it was caused by something else) you have to decide if this is a good investment for you: do you want to keep the car? Are you willing to wrestle with them, perhaps in court?

Comment: One other thing to realize here is, if Kia is saying this to you (whether through the dealership or directly), this is going to be their final word on the matter. Meaning, if you don't take the deal, don't expect to get a better deal. If you don't take the deal and tell them as much, their higher ups can cut the offer to nothing. Having worked at dealerships before, I can tell you this can and does happen. I'm not trying to say, "DO THIS OR ELSE" ... I'm just telling you the probable outcome of trying to get more in your situation. Seriously, to me, $1500 to you out of a $10k bill is not bad.

Comment: Are you the original owner? Kias have 10 year/100K mile warranty (in the US, anyway). If you are not the original owner, take the deal. Manufacturers have no warranty responsibility with subsequent owners. Except for emissions and safety related issues (there are probably others).

Comment: @TimNevins - That isn't *entirely* true ... The original bumper-to-bumper warranty (5yr/60k) transfers to the new owner. Also, if you are a relative of the original owner, you can the get the 10y/100k passed on as well. When I say I sold cars, one of those was Kia ;-)

Comment: My current Kia has a 7 year warranty. The first owner had it 2 years, so I still get 5 years warranty.

Comment: @ Rory Alsop - call Kia customer service and they can give you a definitive answer.

Comment: Having a warranty and getting the manufacturer to pay on it are two different animals. Its dependent on filling out the Kia Change Of Ownership form as well as being prepared to provide all service documentation that shows it has been maintained per the manufacturers guidelines. It's not nearly as easy as it's marketed to be. And whatever you do, DO NOT tell them it has ever been used for commercial purposes. When I worked at Hyundai, a guy called with 105K miles and NO service history. He had a receipt for a third party timing belt that he claimed to have installed. He was out of luck.